# Memory corruption issue

Tags: c++, memory

In my application i am creating a linked list of files. I am allocating space for content of those files in a buffer in each node, then extract Value information from the key=value pairs in the file's buffer and putting in an array :

Code logic is like :

Repeat the following for all the files in the folder

```
{
    fileLinkedList->pFileContentBuffer= new unsigned char[sizeofthefileinbytes]
...
}
```

so i have my buffers allocated now.

Next:
For some of the files(files with key=value pairs on seperate lines) repeat this

```
char* tempBuffer = fileLinkedList->pFileContentBuffer;
...
pEndOfBuffer = tempBuffer + filesize - 2;//just before last CR and LF
char* eachLine = tempBuffer;
eachline = strtok(tempBuffer, "\n\r");//i see that this modifies tempBuffer but 
                                      //replaces 1 byte CR with 1 byte \0 so 
                                      //doesnt look like causing overflow
int i=0;
while(eachline < pEndOfBuffer) {
    stringId[i].text=malloc(sizeofValue + 1);
    int len=strncpy_trimspaces(stringId[i].text,eachline+someoffset,someoffset);

    stringIds[i].text[len] = 0;//null terminate
    i++;
    if ((eachline = strtok(NULL, "\n\r")) == NULL)
         eachline = tempBuffer + filesize;
}
```

Now I have extracted information (Values) from the buffer so i delete it

```
delete[] tempBuffer;
```

This passes for few files and then crashes. All the files are similar in size and format. It crashes with :

`free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x08895cd8 ***`

Please check the code logic above and let me know there is something wrong with the code logic or any way or tool to detect the memory corruption if it is happening.

If i increase the buffersize(`sizeofthefileinbytes`) by few bytes it doesn't crash.

Comment: C++ and C are different languages.  You're clearly using C++ so please don't tag C.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using a std::vector?  If you switch then you can get rid of your new's and deletes.

Comment: Where is an allocation of tempBuffer?

Comment: Adding to what @UKMonkey, since you're using c++ use `std::string` and stop using `char *` pointers for strings which require a lot of ability and experience, and even then are so hard to do right.

Comment: And don't write such a mess of code, that's where you should start. Note that you have `eachLine` and `eachline` which are different identifiers. That's very confusing, so don't do that. Try to write code as if it was meant to be read by a 5 year old and understood. Then, you will notice that bugs are much harder to write.

Comment: Oh, and if you use `new` use `delete`, when allocating an array `new []` and `delete []`. You're not supposed to use `free()` except when the pointer was directly returned by `malloc()`/`realloc()`/`calloc()`, otherwise it's undefined behavior. Nor should you combine `malloc()` and `new` in your code because then it's too hard to know when to use `free()` or `delete` or `delete[]`.

Comment: Is your pFileContentBuffer zero-terminated?  If not, strtok can scan past the end of your buffer on the final token scan...

Comment: `stringId[i].text=malloc(sizeofValue + 1);` -- This will not compile using a C++ compiler.  The return value of `malloc` must be casted to the correct pointer type for a C++ program.  What C++ compiler are you using that accepts this code?

Comment: @mark `new unsigned char[sizeofthefileinbytes]`  if that's accurate, then no, it won't be null terminated.

Comment: *any way or tool to detect the memory corruption if it is happening.* Sounds like a job for [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html).

Comment: "You're clearly using C++" - Looking at the code, this is arguable. Except for that stray `new[]` and `delete[]`, this looks like C code.

Comment: I should have added, `strtok` can scan **and modify** past the end of your buffer if it's not null terminated.  Relying on CRLF at the end of your file for your `while(eachline < pEndOfBuffer)` to work sounds like a recipe for undefined behavior.  Your `sizeofValue` calculation and the `strncpy_trimspaces` function with `someoffset` use are suspect as well...

Comment: `new unsigned char[sizeofthefileinbytes]` -- We have no idea if `sizeofthefileinbytes` is the actual size of the file in bytes.  You say that if you increase this by a few bytes, things start to work.  Did you inspect whether that value is actually correct?

Comment: @UKMonkey: This is a legacy code so was trying to find the problem wit h this.

Comment: @Smit Y cyken : The memory for tempBuffer is allocated in fileLinkedList->pFileContentBuffer= new unsigned char[sizeofthefileinbytes]

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi: I know its a mix of std:string and char * and new and malloc but its a legacy code so trying to find the cause without changing the code. I am calling delete[] for new[]

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This is not the exact code, hidden for security reasons. I have given code fragments to give the logic flow. So in actual code its typecasted.

Comment: @0x5453; with valgrind it doesn't crash

Comment: @UKMonkey: I am not using std list or vectors. I can make the main file list as std::list or std::vector. Each node in the file list contains these internal filecontent buffers. Deleting these buffers causes the crash for some of the files. And files are similar.

Comment: @Mark :The file size is accurate. The size we get from the file system in windows or linux or the char count if we open it in notepad++. This size is the sizeofthefileinbytes. But why is that a problem? Why is null termination required? I use strtok but from the pattern i found i see that it replaces CR with null termination so the buffer should not overrun. Can i use some tool to check the exact memory location which is the cause of problem?

Comment: @Shariq *This is not the exact code, hidden for security reasons* -- So you decided to play "guess my error"?  You should know that a [mcve] is what is needed here, not pseudo-code.

Comment: @Shariq you may find this of use https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Not null-terminating the file contents buffer is a problem if all your files don't end with CRLF.  The way you have it coded, your code will keep on scanning past the end of your buffer until it hits the next 0x00, 0x0d, or 0x0a octet in memory.  This will be somewhat random, AKA undefined.  `strtok` will zero-out the 0x0d or 0x0a corrupting whatever it is.  Not to mention, if you're using `strlen(eachline)` to determine `sizeofValue` your length of the last token will go beyond the end of your file buffer too.  If this isn't your problem, if all your files end in CRLF, then post more code.

Comment: @mark: Yes all my files end in CRLF. The issue seems to be with last strtok call in the loop.As with the fix its not crashing. Answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue seems to be with the last call to strkok in the loop as with the fix its not crashing.

So the relevant code in the code i provided:

```
...
pEndOfBuffer = tempBuffer + filesize - 2;//just before last CR and LF
....
eachline = strtok(tempBuffer, "\n\r");//i see that this modifies tempBuffer but 
                                      //replaces 1 byte CR with 1 byte \0 so 
                                      //doesnt look like causing overflow
.....
while(eachline < pEndOfBuffer) {
   .....
    if ((eachline = strtok(NULL, "\n\r")) == NULL)
         eachline = tempBuffer + filesize;
}
```

In the loop i added a condition :

```
while(eachline < pEndOfBuffer) {
       .....
       if(pEndOfBuffer[0] != '\0'){
        if ((eachline = strtok(NULL, "\n\r")) == NULL)
             eachline = tempBuffer + filesize;
       }else{
         break;
       }
    }
```

The strtok in the loop was executing one time more so seems to be corrupting the memory. I say seems to be because from logic i see that its not required to execute the last time moreover in the last iteration pEndOfBuffer starts with \0 as strtok null terminates the tokens. I dont think i need a tool to point the corrupted memory if i fix the code logic and it doesn't crash.

While exploring found somewhere written that since strtok modifies the original string you should work on a copy. They made the copy with strdup. When i tried it didn't work. I could not understand if i work with a copy, the original would delete but the copy would still have to be deleted and if its corrupting the way the original does, how would it help. Anyway alls well that ends well except the 2 negative points i got :(
Thanks